# Free Feynman propagator calculation

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I stumbled on this integral, which is the free Feynman propagator, in the "QFT for the gifted amateur" book.[image]

I really can't figure out how you do this step. I have tried reducing to the same denominator, I always have an $\epsilon^2$ and some other problems. Could it be possible that these terms are neglected, since the $\epsilon$ comes from a damping factor $e^{-\epsilon t}$?

I should probably mention here $p^0$ is not the energy.

Comment: It is understood in these expressions that you take the limit of $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the two fractions in the first equation to get:
\begin{equation}
\frac{2E_p - 2i\epsilon}{(p^0)^2 - (E_p - i \epsilon)^2}
\end{equation}

Yes, you then ignore the $\epsilon^2$ term in the denominator. Since $\epsilon$ is infinitesimal, reparameterize the $O(\epsilon)$ term $i \epsilon2E_p$ as $i\epsilon$. The $\epsilon$ prescription is for ensuring the correct pole structure, so you can let $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ in the numerator.